# Upload or download files to Filestore mounted on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-filestore

I have mounted a Filestore instance in my Kubernetes cluster. Can I upload some files from my local computer to the Filestore instance? It would be like uploading files to google drive, but in Filestore.

Comment: Does this [instruction on Accessing file shares from Google Kubernetes Engine clusters](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares) answer your question?

Comment: @FaridShumbar No, I need to acces to Filestore with my local machine. The only way I found was using a VPN to connect a VM to VPC... It seems too complex to upload a local file.

Comment: is your Kubernetes cluster on GCP? If yes, then both Filestore and Kubernetes cluster should be in the same Project and [VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc).Then you can follow the instruction I mentioned

Comment: @FaridShumbar. The problem is that the file I wan't to upload is in my local machine and not in my cluster. The solution I found was using Google storage as a bridge to connect Filestore and my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to Filestore outside the VPC network is not possible.

But it is possible to upload/dowload files from a machine outside the VPC network to Google Storage.

So the solution is upload the files to Google storage and then copy them inside the cluster using a pod that executes `gsutil rsync gs://bucket mount-directory`.

The pod can be replaced by a VM machine connected to the VPC network.

Answer (score 1):

Because the files you would like to upload are configuration and credentials files for your app, using Filestore doesn't look like the best choice. Filestore could be justified if you need some data mounted as `ReadWriteMany`, because minimum volume size is 1Tb, and it's too much for configs and credentials.

Instead, a better way to achieve your goal would be using [ConfigMaps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/configmap) to store configuration files and [Secrets](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret) to store credentials. This should be also a [cheaper option](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/pricing):

> You are charged based on the provisioned capacity, not based on the
> capacity used. For example, if you create a 1 TiB instance and store
> 100 GiB of data on it, you incur charges for the entire 1 TiB.

Comment: I am developping a heavy etl workload, so Filestore is needed. Secrets and configmaps are not an option because I need to upload specific folders with objects to the nfs server.